# Xcode static cells with dynamic backgroundColor

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Is there a possibility to set a dynamic backgroundColor with static cells in a UITableView?

For example the user pressed a button in a UITableView and then all cells in the same view change to a specific color.

I already figured out how to set a backgroundColor when the view shows up:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Now I want to achieve the same when the view has already loaded. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the currently visible cells (the ones that have passed over the `willDisplay` milestone) via the [visibleCells](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells) property. You can iterate over this array and do whatever you need:

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Alternatively you can call `reloadData()` on the tableView, this will result in all cells being re-created and re-displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate method called `DidSelect`  this method works when a user tap on a cell in the tableView or inside an element, and returns the index path of selected Cell you can use that to edit background color or anything.
The code should be something like this `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` inside this function you can get the cell using cellForRowAtIndexPath and pass it the selected path and cast it as the cell type you have and then edit it or do whatever.

The full code would look something like this

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
//use the cell object and do what you want 
}
```